# Getting sort details in SlickGrid

Tags: slickgrid

How to get the name/id of the sort column and the sort-order of the column in slickgrid? 
 I'm able to set the sort column using `grid.setSortColumn("column")`, and would like to get the sort column and it's sort order.

Answer (score 3):

```
 grid.getSortColumns()
```

will give you array of objects like this :

```
[Object { columnId= "ProjectProgram",  sortAsc=false}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it in the callback function to onSort:

```
var grid = new Slick.Grid("#sf_grid", dataView, columns, options);

grid.onSort.subscribe(function(e, args) {
    var sortdir = args.sortAsc ? 1 : -1; //get the sort order
    var sortcol = args.sortCol.field;    //get the sort column
});
```

Comment: Also, how would I set the sort direction like setting the SortColumn?

Comment: you can do `dataView.sort(gridManager.comparer, args.sortAsc);` to set the sort direction

Comment: Should the comparer be a separate function that is involved in the sort comparison? I'm not able to find the gridManager.comparer.  I also did find that `grid.SetSortColumn(colName,true/false)` enables to set the Sort column and direction. But that doesn't sort but only toggles the sorting glyph. I would like to invoke the sort method so the grid is sorted.